# Non-existent mapping property [none] specified for property while running test cases

Tags: grails, grails-orm, spock

Below is the domain:

```
package com.test
class Person{
    String name
    static mappedBy= [friends:'none']
    static hasMany=[friends:Person]
}
```

It works well for normal cases, but When I tried to test it by mocking using @Mock annotation in spock for save, got exception below:

```
|  org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.IllegalMappingException:

     Non-existent mapping property [none] specified for property [friends] in class [com.test.Person]
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.config.GormMappingConfigurationStrategy.establishRelationshipForCollection(GormMappingConfigurationStrategy.java:364)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.config.GormMappingConfigurationStrategy.getPersistentProperties(GormMappingConfigurationStrategy.java:206)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.AbstractPersistentEntity.initialize(AbstractPersistentEntity.java:87)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.config.GormMappingConfigurationStrategy.getOrCreateAssociatedEntity(GormMappingConfigurationStrategy.java:675)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.config.GormMappingConfigurationStrategy.establishDomainClassRelationship(GormMappingConfigurationStrategy.java:632)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.config.GormMappingConfigurationStrategy.getPersistentProperties(GormMappingConfigurationStrategy.java:214)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.AbstractPersistentEntity.initialize(AbstractPersistentEntity.java:87)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.AbstractMappingContext.initializePersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:250)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.AbstractMappingContext.initialize(AbstractMappingContext.java:239)
        at grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin.initializeMappingContext(DomainClassUnitTestMixin.groovy:150)
        at grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin.mockDomains(DomainClassUnitTestMixin.groovy:144)
        at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
        at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.JUnitFixtureMethodsExtension$FixtureType$FixtureMethodInterceptor.intercept(JUnitFixtureMethodsExtension.java:145)
        at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:84)
        at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
        at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
        at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
```

Below is the test case:

```
import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(PersonController)
@Mock([Person])
class PersonControllerSpec extends Specification{

    def "test save person"(){
        given:"some person request parameters set for person"
        params.putAll([name:'test234', friends:[], action:'save', controller:'person'])

        when:"perosn.save is called"
        controller.save()

        then:"it must create person object"
        Person.count() == 1
      }

}
```

Any idea what could be done in this case?

Comment: There is already a JIRA on this: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11285

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though there already exists a Jira for same issue which is  [jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11285](http://%20jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11285)

I am able to find out a work around by changing the version of grails-datastore jar as we were getting exception below

```
   Non-existent mapping property [none] specified for property [friends]
```

in GormMappingConfigurationStrategy.java which is under grails-datastore-core jar.

Hence, after upgrading the version to 3.1.5 from 3.0.6 and just to be safe added a check for test environment as well like below

```
        if (Environment.getCurrentEnvironment() == Environment.TEST) {

            compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-core:3.1.5.RELEASE'
        }
```

Now, the jar would only be added for test environment and we can continue with our test cases.

Cheers!!!

Comment: In my case, i went with `test 'org.grails:grails-datastore-core:3.1.5.RELEASE'` in my `BuildConfig` dependencies. Seems to do the job! (grails 2.4.5)

Answer (score 2):

This issue is fixed after grails 2.5.1: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/669

I solved the issue in our project by upgrading to Grails 2.5.5, and updating the used hibernate4 plugin to version hibernate4:5.0.0.RELEASE.